# Other areas of memory (besides stack and heap)?

Tags: memory-management, heap-memory, stack-memory

I know the basics of the [Stack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_%28abstract_data_type%29), and the [Heap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_%28data_structure%29), but are there any other areas in a PC's memory that a program can access and store temporary data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually, you allocate small-sized temporary variables on the stack. You request memory from the heap for larger chunks. But you can also [map a file into memory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory-mapped_file).

Below is a representation of system memory by kind.

**Source:** this very-well explained article: [Understanding Memory](https://web.archive.org/web/20150929093544/http://www.ualberta.ca/CNS/RESEARCH/LinuxClusters/mem.html) that should answer most of your questions.

[image]

Comment: From what I know of windows systems: Windows® does not have a swap, but it has a similar system (the infamous *pagefile.sys*). Also, there are APIs to map a file to memory (see:[Managing Memory-Mapped Files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms810613.aspx)). So, I would say YES, things are similar on windows system. But don't take my word for it.